# RabbitMQ, CloudFoundry, and an External Sender

Tags: java, rabbitmq, jira, cloud-foundry

So right now I am messing around with RabbitMQ on cloud foundry. Im just working with the basics and trying to get a handle on it all.

I have the RabbitMQ client deployed on my cloud foundry instance and I have a spring application running and I can send and receive within the cloud.

Example I went off of word for word is [HERE](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-samples/rabbitmq-cloudfoundry-samples/tree/master/spring)

Now I am looking to send to the cloud from an exterior application. I think I might be having a hard time grasping this concept.

What I was trying to do is use the 'messages' queue created by the example program to push messages too. ( I think this is my misunderstanding).

Can I send messages straight to the client or do I have to have a middle man receiver bined to the client?

This was how I was trying to test the connection and send a message but I get a java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute.

The username, password, virtual host, and other information was taken straight from the client itself.

```
  public void testConnection() throws java.io.IOException {

  ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();

    factory.setUsername("xxxxxxx");
    factory.setPassword("xxxxxxxxxxxx");
    factory.setVirtualHost("xxxxxxxxxxxx");
    factory.setHost("xx.xx.xxx.xx");
    factory.setPort(xxxx);
    Connection conn = factory.newConnection();
    Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
    Channel channel = connection.createChannel();



    channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null);
    String message = "Hello From The Outside!!!";
    channel.basicPublish("", QUEUE_NAME, null, message.getBytes());
    System.out.println(" [x] Sent '" + message + "'");
    channel.close();
    conn.close();
```

What idea am I missing here? Sender, receiver(maybe what im missing), Client to do the queueing (and this is where I want to end for now)

Comment: I used cloudfoundry one year ago, I don't if it is changed. BTW you try to use the 

`RabbitmUri='amqp://aaaabbb:DU0GTgggggsss@lemur.cloudamqp.com/aaaabbb'
factory.setUri(RabbitmqUri);`

You should retrive your URI on the console.

Comment: let me know if you have solved, else I try another way

Comment: This didnt work for me unfortunately. I am still getting:
org.apache.wink.client.ClientRuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried RabbitMQ on cloud foundry, I didn't follow the example.

I create the Rabbitmq Instance:
[image]

Then I opened the RabbitMQ management console:

[image]

I copied the Rabbitmq URL:

[image]

And I used your code in this way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception,URISyntaxException {
      ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
      factory.setUri("amqp://kobqwlov:GANqOND_L4bxqEwqNSQA5BNqGt-X2NqM@lemur.cloudamqp.com/kobqwlov");
      Connection conn = factory.newConnection();
      Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
      Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
      channel.queueDeclare("QUEUE_NAME", false, false, false, null);
      String message = "Hello From The Outside!!!";
      channel.basicPublish("", "QUEUE_NAME", null, message.getBytes());
      System.out.println(" [x] Sent '" + message + "'");
      channel.close();
      conn.close();
    }
```

The example works correctly.

Hope it helps.