# How to publish to RabbitMQ broker in CF from external client?

Tags: rabbitmq, cloud-foundry, mqtt

Is there a way to publish MQTT (or AMQP) messages directly to a RabbitMQ instance running as a Cloud Foundry backing service? If my understanding of the CF architecture is correct, the cloud controller only allows HTTP(S) traffic from external clients in which case the utility of RabbitMQ is reduced to that of an internal queue. Is that a valid assumption?

Comment: Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25936488/rabbitmq-cloudfoundry-and-an-external-sender

Comment: Gas's linked example works if your RabbitMQ service is hosted on an external provider, like CloudAMQP. If you are actually provisioning RabbitMQ servers within your own Cloud Foundry deployment, your assumption is correct: you will need to deploy a microservice that can delegate traffic to the internal RabbitMQ deployment.

Comment: @cepage read here: http://docs.run.pivotal.io/marketplace/services/cloudamqp.html

Comment: Yes, your link references the CloudAMQP service. This is a service broker to a service hosted at cloudamqp.com, which is external to your cloud infrastructure, and addressable over the internet. Compare with this service: http://docs.pivotal.io/rabbitmq-cf/vcap-services.html. This is an example of provisioning a RabbitMQ service within a Cloud Foundry cluster. You can see the address for this service is 10.0.0.x, which is not addressable by an external client (at least, without defining an external network interface).

Comment: @cepage Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

We faced the same problem. Afaik it can be soluted by enabling a tcp enabled domain with TCP routing (https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/adminguide/enabling-tcp-routing.html).

Comment: Link only answers quickly become useless when the link breaks, please copy the substance of the solution into the answer